# When I tried to execute my project on Android studio. It shows following error

Tags: android

When i tried to run my code on android studio. The following error comes:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.com/android/resources/ResourceFolderType
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: show code or any screenshot here

Answer (score 0):

1. Add multiDexEnabled = true in your default Config
2. Add implementation com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1 in your dependencies
3. Application class extend MultiDexApplication instead of just Application